# R geom_area and coord_polar conversion to plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, geom-area

I am trying to convert a ggplot polar chart to a plotly one. I am missing the cumulative of `geom_area` in plotly and the filled color for each trace that is not going to the origin for both trace. The goal is to be as closed as possible to the ggplot view.

```
df <- data.frame(angle = rep(seq(0, 360, 45), 4), frequency = rep(1:9, 4), z = as.character(c(rep(1, 9), rep(2, 9))))
df <- aggregate(frequency ~ angle + z, data = df, sum)

pl <- ggplot(df,aes(x=angle,y=frequency,fill=z)) + geom_area() + coord_polar() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=angle, labels=c("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SO", "O", "NO", "N"))
pl
```

[image: ggplot one]

```
p <- plot_ly(type = 'scatterpolar', mode = "scatter")
for (g in 1:2){
  p <- p %>%
    add_trace(data = df[df$z == g,],
              theta = ~df$angle, r = ~df$frequency,
              opacity = 1, fill = "tozeroy")
}
p <- p %>% layout(
  polar = list(radialaxis = list(angle = 90),
               angularaxis = list(
                 rotation = 90,
                 direction = 'clockwise',
                 ticktext =  c("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SO", "O", "NO", "N"),
                 tickvals = seq(0, 360, 45)
               )
  )
)
p
```

[image: plotly one]

Thank you for any clue on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point for the solution of your problem:

```
k <- 100
df <- data.frame(angle = rep(seq(0, 360, length.out=k), 4), 
                 frequency = rep(1:k, 4), 
                 z = as.character(c(rep(1, k), rep(2, k))))
df <- aggregate(frequency ~ angle + z, data = df, sum)   
df$frequency[df$z==2] <- df$frequency[df$z==2]/2

p <- plot_ly(data=df, type = 'scatterpolar', mode = "lines") %>%
     add_trace(theta=~angle,r=~frequency,fill="toself", color=~z)
p <- p %>% layout(
  polar = list(radialaxis = list(angle = 90),
               angularaxis = list(
                 rotation = 90,
                 direction = 'clockwise',
                 ticktext =  c("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SO", "O", "NO", "N"),
                 tickvals = seq(0, 360, 45)
               )
  )
)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Indeed the smoothing of the plot is missing, you got it by modifying the initial data frame that I can't do