# Circular barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to run [this code](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/circularbarplot.html):

```
# Create dataset
data=data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=c( rep('A', 10), rep('B', 30), rep('C', 14), rep('D', 6)) ,
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)
data = data %>% arrange(group, value)

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar=3
to_add = data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group), ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) = colnames(data)
to_add$group=rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar)
data=rbind(data, to_add)
data=data %>% arrange(group)
data$id=seq(1, nrow(data))
 
# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data=data
number_of_bar=nrow(label_data)
angle= 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust<-ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle<-ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)
 
# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data=data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))
 
# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data = base_data
grid_data$end = grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start = grid_data$start - 1
grid_data=grid_data[-1,]
 
# Make the plot
p = ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  
  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 80, xend = start, yend = 80), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 60, xend = start, yend = 60), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 40, xend = start, yend = 40), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 20, xend = start, yend = 20), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),4), y = c(20, 40, 60, 80), label = c("20", "40", "60", "80") , color="grey", size=3 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  ylim(-100,120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)
 
p
```

In order to have this plot:

[image]

but I have an error, I think it comes from the "base_data" dataframe:

[image]

Also is there any possibility to make this graph as a reactive plot (when moving the mouse on the barplot you could see the frequency or the percentage) ??

Answer (score 0):

The `annotate` error might be due to another package that you have loaded. I would specify the package for `annotate`.

```
ggplot2::annotate(
  "text",
  x = rep(max(data$id), 4),
  y = c(20, 40, 60, 80),
  label = c("20", "40", "60", "80") ,
  color = "grey",
  size = 3 ,
  angle = 0,
  fontface = "bold",
  hjust = 1
)
```

For making a reactive plot, you'll need to use `plot_ly`, as `ggplotly` does not support `coord_polar`: [see here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/878). Here are a couple of examples of using `plot_ly` for reactive plots for a [piechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737923/r-convert-ggplot-piechart-into-plotly) and a [polar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869721/r-geom-area-and-coord-polar-conversion-to-plotly).